# Silverlight tooltip words are reversed

Tags: silverlight, grid, tooltip

For some reason the tooltip in silverlight is reversing the text displayed.

Here is the code

```
            // Create the colored rectangle
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();

            // Set the grid row and column
            Grid.SetRow(rect, i);
            Grid.SetColumn(rect, 0);

            // Set the rectangle into the UI
            LegendColorGrid.Children.Add(rect);

            // Create the tooltip for the item
            ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
            tip.Content = contentList[i].UnitLabel;
            tip.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Right;
            tip.PlacementTarget = rect;

            // Set the tooltip into the UI
            ToolTipService.SetToolTip(rect, tip);
```

For example the tooltip is supposed to read '< -85 °C' but the tooltip shown says 'C° 85- >'

Comment: Do you have some sort of localization running or a RightToLeft set on a textblock template or something? Why wouldn't ya just do all this in XAML?

Comment: So the 8 and 5 are still in the correct order but your less than is now a greater than???

Comment: @Chrisw. It goes grid > wrap panel > grid > rectangle. The wrappanel has a right to left flow direction.  EDIT: it appears to have to do with the wrap panel setting flow direction. But i need the wrap panel to actually flow from right to left.

Comment: @steve. Yup, its odd. If i set the flow direction left to right on the text the text just shows up with each letter flipped 180.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears to be because of a want to make a stack panel flow from right to left instead of the default value of left to right.

I set the flowDirection on the stack panel and it was causing the flow direction of the containing tool tips to basically wack out and do some crazy ass stuff like reversing every single letter and reversing some words but not others. No freaking idea why this is happening but if i set the flow direction to LeftToRight on the grid that is directly inside each wrap panel block the contained contents starts behaving by normal rules again.